# Declaration of a Verilog function in a header file

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, xilinx, iverilog

When I try to compile a testbench which includes a header file which contains a function declaration Icarus Verilog (v10.0 stable) aborts with the following error:

```
mpeg.vh:133: error: function declarations must be contained within a module.
```

This error is quite clear. However, the header file is in fact included *inside* of a module (the testbench). Since an include directive should just be replaced by the text inside the respective header file the function declaration is in fact contained within a module (contrary to what the error message claims).
I have used this header file before with Xilinx ISE (fuse/isim) which worked just as intended. There wasn't even a warning.

Is it allowed to declare a function inside a header file (for later inclusion *inside* of a module)?

I was unable to find the answer to this question in the Verilog LRM (IEEE 1364-2001, Chapter 10).

Example:

test.vh:

```
function integer foo;
  input integer a;
begin
  foo = a;
end
endfunction
```

test.v:

```
module bar;
`include "test.vh"
endmodule
```

Call iverilog: `iverilog -o test.o -Wall test.v test.vh`

Comment: Seems like a tool issue. Many times, I prefer keeping the clog2 function in common area. Do you have updated version of iverilog?

Comment: When calling only the preprocessor with `iverilog -E -o test.o -Wall test.v test.vh` the preprocessed output shows that the header file is in fact "included" twice, once inside the module where the `\`include` directive is and once again after `endmodule`. So my mistake here seems to be the inclusion of test.vh on the command line. Removing test.vh from the list of source files when calling iverilog makes the error go away. Yet, the original question about the valid scope for a function declaration remains.

Comment: I think you want `iverilog -o test.o -Wall test.v` (without test.vh). The test.vh file is included with the `included statement

Comment: I guess, there is issue related to `include, as this is the normal practice followed throughout the industry (Defining functions in other file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the old Verilog standard, nothing is allowed outside the scope of a `module/endmodule` pair. Compiler directives (things that start with `) are an exception because they are pre-processed before any other syntax.

SystemVerilog added the concept of a [compilation unit](http://go.mentor.com/unit-vs-root), which allows code to exist outside the scope a module. But it also added packages that can be [imported instead of `included](http://go.mentor.com/package-import-versus-include) to get rid of the problem of having a function multiply defined when you what one of them.

Comment: What do you consider the "old" Verilog standard? Everything before SV?

Comment: An "old" standard is any standard that has been obsoleted by another standard.

Comment: Well there are a couple of those "old" standards then :-) But I get your point.